# Is there a difference running Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu locally vs Ubuntu on Virtual Machine?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ruby, ruby-on-rails

More or less - as in the topic. I'm planning to format my PC, currently I have dual-boot with Win 7/Ubuntu 16.04. For my daily job I'm working mainly with Windows software but have quite a lot of irregular breaks that I can spend on programming. To do it though, I have to save all the progress and restart the PC every time in order to boot Ubuntu which is a bit of a pain in the ass for me.

I would like to install Windows 10 with Ubuntu on virtual box. Is there any difference in how does Ubuntu behave on VM and locally? I would like to be sure that I won't have a problem with running PostgreSQL, connecting with github or deploying apps to servers. Is anyone using a similar combo?

Comment: Virtualization always implies using *less* and often *different* hardware than running the same OS normally in the same machine. You need to list the hardware requirement for the software you intend to run in the VM and then adjust its settings to match what you need. Of course, this also depends on the actual hardware you have, whether or not it supports virtualization and how much resources you can assign to the VM. Unfortunately, if you're asking such question, I'm afraid you don't know enough yet to do what you want.

Comment: Lol at that preaching at the end. It really isn't a rocket science to set up a virtual machine and check requirements. It's obvious VM runs slower than local system and utilizes hardware differently, that's not what the question was about, I was asking specifically about Rails which tends to be a bit moody environment and I wanted to confirm they are no other problems than a slower performance :P Nevertheless, thank you for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functional difference between running your environment on your PCs hardware, or as a virtual machine.

Your VM will have less CPU power and have less memory, but on modern computers that shouldnt be an issue.  As long as you set up the networking properly, you should have the same access to any networks your host PC has.